# How to escape single quote in url query string with asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building the url in my web application and I am trying to pass a name as a query string, Bob O'Neal, which to my surprise does not seemed to be escaped properly with UrlEncode and there seems to be nothing on the net which talks about how to handle this?

Is there an elegant solution to properly handle escaping single quotes in query strings?

Comment: Can you provide URLEncode()'s output?

Comment: Useful information on this subject: http://robertcorvus.com/breaking-change-in-asp-net-4-0-affects-query-strings-with-single-quotes/

Comment: is this in Firefox only? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165115/server-urlencode-apostrophe-in-firefox

Comment: Are you trying to escape this URI client-side or server-side? If you have a choice (say, on an input form being submitted) I would recommend client-side where you could simply use Javascript to encode the characters; single quotes should be encoded properly.

Comment: The output looks like this for Bob O'Neal => Bob+O'Neal which handled the space but not the single quote.

I am trying to do this on the server side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are storing the URL in a javascript statement to be executed on the client, then you need to do:

```
sURL = sURL.Replace("'", "\'");
```

Comment: This is the answer, after more reading it turns out single quote do not need to be escaped, and it is when I am using it in the javascript that it does not like it, thank you.

Comment: JS need also some other `Replace` for other strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, or its more secure counterpart, to encode the query string, but you shouldn't need to. Note that you will be able to retrieve it unencoded in the QueryString dictionary.

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("'"); //%27
```

Comment: This did not work prior to .NET 4.0.  See http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770143

Answer (score 1):

There's a `UrlPathEncode` method as well, have you tried that one?

Answer (score 0):

[this user had a similar problem](http://forums.asp.net/t/1256092.aspx/1)

UrlEncode encodes a single quote (') but not a slanted single quote(`)

If this is not the case in your 'error' (which it appears the OP of that topic claimed it was not) you will have to implement a `UseMe` function (see post) like described.